# Error while doing Watershed analysis using Python

Tags: qgis, python, watershed, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to do watershed analysis using Python in jupyter notebook. Whenever I am passing commands regarding watershed delineation in Python I am getting output as raster matrix and when I am plotting it in graph using `imshow()` command I am getting squared images in graph and not the desired output.
I am passing commands such as:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import geopandas as gpd
from pysheds.grid import Grid
import mplleaflet
%matplotlib inline
import tifffile as tiff

grid = Grid.from_raster(r'D:\...\ASTGTMV003_N19E073_dem.tif', data_name='dem')
grid.view('dem')
```

output :

```
Raster([[202., 204., 204., ..., 517., 524., 532.],
        [204., 202., 202., ..., 514., 519., 523.],
        [202., 201., 200., ..., 519., 516., 519.],
        ...,
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ..., 606., 606., 604.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ..., 607., 607., 603.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ..., 607., 612., 610.]], dtype=float32)
```

...
And then while calculating catchment area:

Flow dir:

```
grid.flowdir(data='inflated_dem', out_name='dir', dirmap=dirmap)
grid.view('dir')
```

Output:

```
Raster([[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   2.,   2., ...,  -1.,   4.,   0.],
        [  0.,   4.,   1., ...,  64.,  -1.,   0.],
        ...,
        [  0.,   4.,   4., ...,   1., 128.,   0.],
        [  0.,  -1.,  -1., ..., 128.,   1.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.]], dtype=float32)
```

But then I plotted it in image using:

```
plotFigure(grid.dir,'Flow Direction','viridis')
```

[image]

And I got image but while calculating catchment area
By specifying x and y:

```
x, y = 73.6, 19.6
grid.catchment(data='dir', x=x, y=y, dirmap=dirmap, out_name='catch',
               recursionlimit=15000, xytype='label')
grid.clip_to('catch')
catch = grid.view('catch')
plt.imshow(catch)
```

I am getting output as
[image]

Why is this occurring?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the extent of your ASTER DTM tile 'ASTGTMV003_N19E073_dem.tif' is from 19 N to 18 N. The coordinates in the file name are the NW corner. But you chose a y value of 19.6. That would be outside (north) of the tile.

Comment: Actually I am getting 'y' extent from 19.0-20.0(19.0,19.2,19.4,19.6,19.8,20.0)and ' x' extent from 73.0-74.0 (73.0,73.2,73.4,73.6,73.8,74.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a fairly common error associated with `pysheds` that to my knowledge has not been fixed (I moved away from `pysheds` to TopoToolbox for exactly this error). There is an open issue on this still on [github](https://github.com/mdbartos/pysheds/issues/126). It sounds like one solution is to add to the `catchment` function the following:

```
grid.catchment(data='dir', x=x, y=y, dirmap=dirmap, out_name='catch',
               recursionlimit=15000, xytype='label', snap = 'center')
```

The default is to snap the x,y pour point to the corner of a pixel, which is likely causing the odd watershed delineation. The default:

```
def nearest_cell(self, x, y, affine=None, snap='corner'):
```

My experience with this has been that sometime it fixes it, sometimes it doesn't. I have not been able to figure out the exactly reasoning for it occurring, I think it has something to do with coordinate systems. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the function `grid.catchment()` doesn't work. My coordinates match between the dem and the outlet. I try your proposition with `snap='corner'`.
Do you have other propositions because I  cannot find?

grid.flowdir --> whork
[image]
grid.catchment --> strange result
[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/216094)